# "sympathetic" : one who "feels" sympathy or "deserves" sympathy?

Tags: word-usage

Can one who others feel sympathy **for**, be described as *sympathetic*?
I've always believed that *sympathetic* only describes one who **bestows** sympathy, not one who **receives** sympathy.

Incorrect Example?

> Audiences found the blind orphan to be a sympathetic character.

I see similar examples so much in movie reviews that now I'm doubting myself!

Comment: Have you found a dictionary giving the 'deserving / attracting / in need of' sense? Can you give a couple of examples from reviews?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I'm surprised; using sympathetic to mean attracting sympathy is a lot less common than I thought!  It took a bit of searching, but according to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sympathetic), it isn't incorrect:

> 1 Feeling, showing, or expressing sympathy: *he was sympathetic toward staff with family problems*
>
> 2.1 (Of a person) attracting the liking of others: *Audrey develops as a sympathetic character*

So, while apparently far less common than using it to describe someone giving sympathy, using it to describe someone receiving sympathy seems to be a valid use.

Comment: That is not the OED.

Comment: Ye gods, I completely misread that. My apologies!